# How to control the zoom amount in Cesium.Camera.flyTo ?

Tags: zoom, cesium

The following code flies the camera to a particular destination. But how do I control the zoom on the particular destination?

```
   viewer.camera.flyTo({
      destination : Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-117.16, 32.71, 15000.0),
      duration : 20.0
    });
```

Changing Cesium.Camera.defaultZoomAmount doesn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Cartesian3](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/Cartesian3.html?classFilter=Cartesian) takes three parameters. The third parameter being the Z component which takes care of the height at which camera is placed. Varying Z component helps us control the zoom on the camera to a particular destination identified by the first two parameters, X component and Y component (latitude, longitude).

Comment: This answer is phrased incorrectly.  `Cartesian3.fromDegrees` does take three parameters, the third being the height.  But `fromDegrees` is just a helper function that creates a `Cartesian3` from lon/lat/alt, and internally the `Cartesian3` itself is an actual Cartesian with X, Y, and Z in meters, none of which correspond exactly to height.  But by using the `fromDegrees` helper function, this implementation detail is effectively hidden, so is safe to ignore in simple cases like this.

Answer (score 2):

The destination is allowed to be a [Rectangle](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/Rectangle.html) instead of a Cartesian3.  When using a rectangle, the camera's height (zoom level) will be set such that it can see the corners of the rectangle.  Use a larger rectangle for a more zoomed-out look.

For a working example of this, load the [Sandcastle Camera Demo](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/index.html?src=Camera.html&label=Showcases) and click the pull-down to select "Fly to Rectange".  The demo runs this code:

```
var west = -90.0;
var south = 38.0;
var east = -87.0;
var north = 40.0;
var rectangle = Cesium.Rectangle.fromDegrees(west, south, east, north);

viewer.camera.flyTo({
    destination : rectangle
});

// Show the rectangle.  Not required; just for show.
viewer.entities.add({
    rectangle : {
        coordinates : rectangle,
        fill : false,
        outline : true,
        outlineColor : Cesium.Color.WHITE
    }
});
```

Comment: I agree with you on the [Rectangle] (http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/Rectangle.html) zoom options but that requires four parameters. What if I need to point to a particular destination using only lat and long and control the zoom levels on it? Is there any way I can do that?